# dpkg: error: dpkg frontend is locked by another process

Tags: command-line, dpkg

When running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, I am getting the following error on my terminal. Can some one please help?

[image: dpkg: error: dpkg frontend is locked by another process]

```
dpkg: error: dpkg frontend is locked by another process
```

Comment: Close ALL your other package managers, app stores, and similar applications. Do not interrupt any in progress; wait for them to finish.

Comment: Have you tried suggestion at https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-could-not-get-lock-error-ubuntu?

Answer (score 14):

Let all the ongoing processes/installations/updates to complete, retry once all the installation/updates get completed. It will work.

If you've not started any installation/updates then try the following method.

Use the following command in the terminal, it will give you PID

```
sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
```

then copy the value of PID and execute the following command with adding your copied PID in place of

```
sudo kill -9 <PID>
```

Comment: i m having the same problem here, i did what Vipul Patil said, but its responded with: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `PID'

Comment: you need to add your pid within arrow bracket instead of 'PID' literal word.